# replace() method of FragmentTransaction is not working expectedly

Tags: android

replace() method of FragmentTransaction is not working expectedly...

1). I added a fragment f1 and committed it.
2). I added a fragment f2 and committed it.
3). I used replace() method and used fragment f3 to replace whatever was on fragment transaction object.

It removes only fragment f1, but not fragment f2. So f2 and f3 are visible.
What I expect is , only fragment f3 should be shown.

I am using LinearLayout with vertical TextView as CONTAINER.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

`mFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

Comment: I am not using Backstack.

Answer (score 0):

According the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html) the replace method of FragmentTransaction will:

> **Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container.**
>
> public abstract FragmentTransaction replace (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
>
> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling **remove(Fragment)** for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId **and then add(int, Fragment, String)** with the same arguments given here.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - containerViewId   - Identifier of the container whose fragment(s) are to be replaced.
> - fragment   - The new fragment to place in the container.
> - tag   - Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the fragment with  FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String).
>
> **Returns**
>
> Returns the same FragmentTransaction instance.

Could it be your expectation is wrong?

Comment: Still not working. I specifically passed TAG ["f2"] for fragment f2 in call to ft.replace(R.id.layout,f3, "f2"); and then ft.commit(), But still, f2 is visible.

Comment: And one more thing. 3rd argument in ft.replace() refers to the optional TAG name for the new fragment being added instead of fragment that needs to be replaced.

Comment: Solution is: In API documentation it is being said that replace() works as combination of remove() and add(). But it is not the case. You need to call remove(Fragment f) first and then add();. It works!!!!!

Comment: In your question can you please add the source code how you called it initially and how you solved it. That would be helpful if someone else has the same problem. (But I'm still not sure why it didn't work for you initially).

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout as a container instead of LinearLayout.